# Disable Document-Based functionality on a Cocoa Application

Tags: xcode, macos, nsdocument, document-based

I started a Document-Based project on XCode for a MacOS project. I realize now that i don't need this functionality and its potentially causing problems and delays in my progress.

Is there a way to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

To keep documents from opening, all you have to do is implement `application(_: openFile:)` or `application(_: openFiles:)` in your app delegate.  These are the methods that are called when *any* file is opened, and by default these messages are just shuffled off to `NSDocumentController`, which is responsible for the whole document-based-app thing.  If you implement one of those methods to do something other than invoke the `NSDocument` architecture, you can keep the ability to open files while removing the rest of the document-based system.

Keep in mind, though, that menu items such as Open and Open Recent will still be routed to the `NSDocumentController` and use the old behavior.  To completely remove the document-based functionality:

- Get rid of your `NSDocument` subclass(es) (or just disable them)
- Remove the references to those classes in your Info.plist
- Remove any document-specific menu items (like Save)

  I'd recommend that you hang on to the Open item; being able to open documents is handy even in a single-window or shoebox app.
- If you have an `NSDocumentController` or a subclass in your main nib file or main storyboard scene, remove it or at the very least make sure that no actions are explicitly routed to it
- If you have any code that uses `NSDocumentController`, get rid of it